# How to strip a string of all formatting

Tags: expansion, metadata

I'm using XeLaTeX with Polyglossia.

I have a string like this

```
Three \emph{blind} Mice, Émile.
```

saved in a macro, thus:

```
\gdef\foobar{Three \emph{blind} Mice, Émile.}
```

and I want to send the text in \foobar into the metadata of a PDF using \pdfinfo{}, thus:

```
\pdfinfo{/Title (\foobar)}
```

It doesn't work, because the text in \foobar is sent into the PDF with messy expansion.  And the Unicode chars are also messed up.

I've tried some ideas using \noexpand, \expandafter, \toks, but without any success.

Any ideas?

PS don't tell me to use \hyperref's "pdfauthor={}"mechanism, because that clashes with the pdfx package and I can't use it.  And I don't want to use pdfx's xmpdata method either. I'm after a solution to the specific issue mentioned, how to change "Three \emph{blind} Mice, Émile."into "Three blind Mice, Emile."  Even "Three blind Mice, Émile." would be an improvement.

Comment: Please, add a minimal example of code to play with.

Comment: Since which version is `\pdfinfo` of pdfTeX supported in XeTeX?

Comment: Using `\begingroup
\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{#1}%
\pdfinfo{/Title (\foobar)}
\endgroup` should do the trick.  If there other formatting commands, they will need to be redefined within the group.

Answer (score 1):

Using `\pdfinfo` is not recommended, if package `hyperref` is used:

- `\pdfinfo` is a low-level driver-specific command, only supported in pdfTeX and LuaTeX.
- The extracting of markup, the right encoding, the escaping of unmatched parentheses, ... must be done manually.

Package `hyperref` provides options for setting the metadata. The string is automatically processed by `\pdfstringdef`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={Three \emph{blind} Mice, Émile.},
}

\begin{document}
  Lorem ipsum.
\end{document}
```

Option `pdfencoding=auto` takes care of the encoding of bookmark strings and information meta data. The PDF format supports two encodings:

- PDFDocEncoding (8-bit)
- Unicode (UTF-16BE)

with `auto` the string is encoded in PDFDocEncoding, if it fits there, otherwise Unicode is used.

Comment: See my PS comment in my original posting above. I can't use \hypersetup because it clashes with another package.

Comment: @Dominik If you are using package `pdfx` you *must* stick to its interface (`\Author`, ...), because the package also has to write the meta data in XML format. Both entries of the author in the PDF meta data and the XML meta data should be the same. If you don't want to use `pdfx` then do not use it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered \pdfstringdef, documented in the hyperref manual.  It does exactly what I need.

Comment: Please add a mininal example of how to use that macro.

Comment: \pdfstringdef{\TempMice}{Three \emph{blind} Mice, Émile.}

/pdfinfo{
    (\TempMice)
}

Answer (score 0):

\pdfstringdef turns accented characters into octal escape sequence.

Turns : LIPSUM ÉÈÇÀÙÎÏ éèçàùîï 231

Into : LIPSUM \311\310\307\300\331\316\317 \351\350\347\340 231

[image: pdfstringdef octal sequence]

From [How to make a glowing text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545901/how-to-make-a-glowing-text/)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\Huge

Assume pdf\TeX

\def\exText{LIPSUM ÉÈÇÀÙÎÏ éèçàùîï 231}

\makeatletter

    Reverse engineer the contour package.

    Here is an MWE\\
    \leavevmode
    \begingroup
        \color{green}%
        \con@coloroff
        \pdfliteral{%
            q % enter a scope
            1 j % Set line join style
            1 J % Set line cap style
            1 Tr % Set text rendering mode
            2.5 w % Set line width (in PostScript Point)
        }%
        \rlap{\exText}%
        \pdfliteral{%
            Q % leave the scope
        }%
    \endgroup
    \mbox{\exText}


    Now use TikZ.\\
    \pdfstringdef\plainstr{\exText} % Extraction chaine 'nettoyée'
    \leavevmode
    \pgfsys@beginscope% = pdf literal q
    \pgfsetroundjoin% = 1 J
    \pgfsetroundcap% = 1 j
    \pdfliteral{1 Tr}% no pgf alternative
    \foreach\ind in{10,...,1}{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\per{(11-\ind)*5}%
        \color{green!\per}%
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\ind/2}%
        \rlap{\plainstr}%
    }%
    \pgfsys@endscope % = pdf literal Q
    \plainstr

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, although I don't understand how this is supposed to be an answer to the present question.

Comment: This is not an answer, this is comment, but as a "freshman", I have to accumulate 50 "likes" before I can comment, but not post an answer. Yet I can comment my own "answer". Go figure... This online gaming/ranting platform have strange rules :/